# trouble in php mail function

Tags: php, sendmail

My php.ini looks like this :

```
    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/smtp
    SMTP = localhost
    ; http://php.net/smtp-port
    smtp_port = 25

    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
    sendmail_from = you@yourdomain

    ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-path
    sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f akeel_mn@yahoo.com"
```

and my php code looks like this :

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['mail']))
    {
$success = mail("akeel26@gmail.com","hello","Welcome to our site!");
if($success)
{
    echo 'mail send';
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
    }
    ?>
```

when I run the prog it displays as mail send but the mail doesn't get delivered to the intended recipient..
does anybody know what's wrong? is there any more configuration to be made other than in the php.ini?

Comment: Your server is on Linux or Windows ?

Comment: No need to bold **everything**

Comment: its windows........................

Comment: Are you running an SMTP server (e.g. Exchange) on localhost?

Comment: Well sounds like an issue with the setup of your smtp server. Most likely the mail is stuck in its queue 'cause it cannot send it. You did check that, didn't you?

Comment: am kind of new to php so i exactly don't know :-/ what do i have to do get the SMTP server up & running?

Comment: @arkascha : do you know what has to be done in order to send a mail?

Comment: Running an smtp server has nothing to do with php. You tell php in the ini file to use an smtp server running on localhost. Do you have a smtp server running on localhost? If not, do you have access to any other mail server? Maybe one of your internet provider? Or your mail provider? You do need an smtp server cause that's how mails get send. If you don't run an smtp server yourself, then you have to look for one you can use. Which one do you use when sending a message using a 'normal' email program? I suggest you read a bit about how email actually works. Few people know that, actually...

Comment: @arkascha : at the moment no i guess.. if you don't mind can you please tell me how to run a SMTP server?

Comment: If you don't know what it is then you don't want to do that. Look for a server you can use instead. Believe me. Installing and configuring such servers is not trivial without opening massive security problems. If you still want to do it, well, then you have to install an smtp server. But again: you don't want to do that, especially not on a MS-Windows system. Those systems are a very bad base for such tasks.

Comment: @arkascha : k thank you very very much for your reply's.. ill try to configure a mail server..

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosted on a site that supports email or hosting from home? A lot of times home ISP providers will block all outgoing port 25 traffic. so it will sit in the queue and show as timed out.

i also notice your missing headers. dont know if that makes a difference.

```
$to = "whoever@wherever.com;
$subject = "About mail";
$message = "something to say"
$headers = "From: noreply@wherever.com";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```